# source for eclipse plugin.xml page

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I would like to know where can I find the code which eclipse uses to display the forms in the plugin.xml file. In particular I am looking for the form layout used in the extension tab in the plugin.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the eclipse plugins into your workspace by using import -> Plugins and Fragments from the package explorer.  Then use the following options:

- Select from all plug-ins and fragments found at the specified location
- import from the target platform with source folders (last option)

Import the org.eclipse.pde.ui plugin

The code you seek is in org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.plugin

More specifically, the ExtensionPointsPage class

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Eclipse's plugin search doesn't work for referenced plugins.  To do these searches I created a workspace that contains all the plugins from my eclipse install as source folders.  I just open the workspace and perform my plugin search there.  Just open the search dialog and choose plugin.